# Core dump in libc exit call

Tags: c++, gdb, solaris, coredump

I am seeing a core dump in solaris at the exit procedure of my program.. How to debug and fix this kind of core dump?

```
(gdb) where
#0  0xff2cc0c0 in kill () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#1  0x0004dac0 in run_before_killed_handler (sig=11) at NdmpServer.cpp:1186
#2  signal handler called
#3  0xfee0ad50 in ?? ()
#4  0x00060a6c in proc_cleanup ()
#5  0xff2421ac in _exithandle () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#6  0xff2305d8 in exit () from /usr/lib/libc.so.1
#7  0x0003431c in _start ()
```

Comment: You could start by telling us what is at line `NdmpServer.cpp:1186`. Then work your way down the backtrace till you find the problem. `proc_cleanup` might also be useful to see.

Comment: run_before_killed_handler  (NdmpServer.cpp:1186) is an sig handler for all signals. sig 11 is the SIGSEV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program apparently uses [atexit(3C)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/atexit-3c.html#scrolltoc) to register an exit handler. The problem is occuring in that handler.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the finer details of Solaris memory layouts, `0xfee0ad50` seems to be on the OS side. What OS call are you trying (and failing) to make in `proc_cleanup`?